# Is there potentially an endianness trouble here?

Tags: c, putchar

I would like to write a function such as `putchar`, with the help of `write` function.

```
#include <unistd.h>

ssize_t f(int fd, int c) {
    return write(fd, &c, 1);
}
```

But I think there could be an endianness problem here, isn't it ? So should I use `sizeof (int)` ? I am a bit confused, I don't know how to process (need a cast to `unsigned char` ?).

Comment: Whether or not there's an endianness issue depends on who *consumes* the data that you're writing.

Comment: int size is 4 byte and here you are only writing 1 byte so how you going to handle other 3 bytes?

Comment: @Mr.32 In context, it is erroneous to call `f` with `c` having a value outside the range 0 through `UCHAR_MAX`.  I agree that this is not a good API definition, but under some circumstances (e.g. backward compatibility with `stdio`) one might be stuck with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is potentially an endianness problem here.  The cure is to pass `c` as an `unsigned char` rather than as an `int`.

```
ssize_t
f(int fd, unsigned char c)
{
    return write(fd, &c, 1);
}
```

The `<stdio.h>` routines work with `int`s mostly for historical reasons.  They are very old, and contain many interface design decisions that would be considered incorrect nowadays.  Do not use them as a template.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, good catch, there is an endian problem. If you want to keep the function signature, you need to temporarily store the data into an unsigned char and then output it;

```
#include <unistd.h>

ssize_t f(int fd, int c) {
    unsigned char ch = (unsigned char)c;
    return write(fd, &ch, sizeof(unsigned char));
}
```

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to use a `char` to store the value of an `int` ? Because we don't know the sign of a `char`.

Comment: @Kirilenko `putchar` takes an int and is (reading the macos documentation here) documented to convert it to an unsigned char (I mistakenly used char in the code) before outputting it. In other words, the signedness is documented to be unsigned.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I don't find any precision about it in the standard.

Comment: Oups, apologize, I've found it (§7.21.7.3). Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: The cast is unnecessary, and `sizeof(<any modifiers> char)` is defined to be 1 by the standard, so you should just say 1.  However, this is indeed the correct approach if you need the function to take an `int`.